# Django Apache mod_wsgi 500

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django application deployed on CentOS.  Here is what my httpd.conf file looks like:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
<VirtualHost *:80>

    WSGIDaemonProcess safe python-path=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup safe
    WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/safe/safe/wsgi.py

    <Directory /opt/safe/safe/>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: This is my `TEMPLATE_DIRS`

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    "/opt/safe/static/templates",
    "/var/www/html/static/templates",
)
```

EDIT: This is my Admin/Emailing setup:

```
ADMINS = (
# ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
('David', 'david@localhost'),
)

SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'david@localhost'
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
```

In my templates directory, I have defined a custom `500.html` file.  When I set my `settings.py` to have `DEBUG = False`, I cannot get anywhere on my site without seeing this custom 500.html page.

What's even more strange is the fact that there are no errors in the log files - so I am unsure of where to look or how to proceed.  I know it can see the templates because of my custom 500.html file, but I am not sure what is causing the 500 Internal Server errors.

EDIT: After further configuration, I managed to get some errors output (thanks to @Matt Stevens), here is the log output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 89, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 55, in process_request
host = request.get_host()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 223, in get_host
"Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): %s" % host)
SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): [my ip address]
```

Comment: when you set debug to true, does everything function normally ?

Comment: yes - I can access everything normally (all my URLs work, everything).

Comment: What does your template_dirs tuple look like ?

Comment: Aren't you receiving the error e-mails?

Comment: I am not receiving any emails - I've added my email settings, just want it to send to my local account (my username is "david").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add my IP address to the "ALLOWED_HOSTS" in my `settings.py` file.  Thanks to the error logging, I was finally able to see that.

Actual code:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['my.server.ip.address']
```

After an Apache restart, everything is working properly now!

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post the solution! Never knew about `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, looks like it's a new security feature: http://git.io/9Ytk6A

Comment: Well, it's not your IP address you should add there, but a valid HTTP-Host. When accessing your server by using its IP address, this is the same, but you probably want to set this to a FQDN in production environments. See the [Django documentation about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

Comment: This answer gives one of the possible error [Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15100463/6709630) gives the logging solution that helps you to find all errors possible!

Answer (score 9):

You could try logging everything to a file to naildown the cause.

Add a logfile for django on the system :

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/django
sudo touch /var/log/django/error.log
sudo chown <user>:<user> /var/log/django/error.log
chmod 600 /var/log/django/error.log
```

Then add this in `settings.py` :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'logfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/error.log'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

Et voilà! Just run your django server & `less /var/log/django/error.log` tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Not sure why it wasn't writing anything at first - but after a few other changes and some permission modifications, I was able to get the log to spit stuff out.  Thanks!

Comment: That is the speedest way to find: `sudo mkdir /var/log/django; sudo touch /var/log/django/error.log; sudo chown <user>:<user> /var/log/django/error.log; chmod 600 /var/log/django/error.log` then adding your config and voilà !