# Django internal server error with no error messages

Tags: django, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

Another django server error problem.

I had my site up and running for a while until I restarted my server today.  Now I get an internal server error.  There is nothing related in the apache log.  Debug is True in settings.py and is confirmed to be True using the shell. I have no idea what is going on and I can't get any information about the error from my system.

This is on OSX 10.7 if it matters.

wsgi.py:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/Users/dpawlows/django/zone/'

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

sys.path.append('Users/dpawlows/django')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so
#WSGIPythonHome /opt/local/bin
WSGIScriptAlias /zone /Users/dpawlows/django/zone/apache/wsgi.py
<Directory "/Users/dpawlows/django/zone/">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /Users/dpawlows/django/zone/register/static/
<Directory /Users/dpawlows/django/zone/register/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Update: After pulling a backup copy of the site that I am 100% sure worked and testing it out, I get the exact same problem, so the issue doesn't seem to be related to the app.  It has to be something with apache that isn't loading correctly, or with the db, but I'm not sure what, as apache and the mysql are running.  Any other thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do you know it's an internal server error if you have nothing displayed? Not even an error number (403 ? 500 ?). Do you have an htaccess somewhere?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: That's the error that comes up when I go to the site.  I don't get any other error messages in error_log or anything like that.

Comment: I'm using django 1.4.3

Comment: You could enable logging, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15100463/1428653

Comment: when I do that, I don't get anything in the log, even if I open up permissions.  What worries me is I can't tell if changing settings.py does anything.  So I moved settings.py to a temp file, nothing changed at all.  Same 505 error.  I don't know if that says something about settings.py not getting read or something?

Comment: Figured out the answer.  This is dumb.  I had two versions of apache running.  No idea how that happened, but the machine restart automatically started two processes.  Once I killed the second version everything was running again.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight you can try changing 'settings' for 'zone.settings', if this don't fix maybe can throw an error message on the Apache's error_log.