# Django static files suddenly disappeared 404 error

Tags: django

I have weird question, but can anyone know what happened?

I have made Django app and everything worked fine, and then restarted server and start again Django with command:

And then static files do not loaded (CSS, images ...)... I get 404 error.
What happened???
Please help... Maybe I have to run it on the other way? I really do not know what happened, because everything worked fine, and then after I started that again everything go wrong..

```
nohup python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &
```

This is the command that I used to start django (server) again..

Comment: Did you change from `DEBUG=True` to `Debug=False` by any chance?

Comment: I did it few months before, but it worked fine ...

Comment: Thanks man, I put again DEBUG = TRUE and it worked... Thanks a lot..

Comment: Can you explain me what happened, because it worked fine and what is for DEBUG = TRUE...

Comment: in short, `DEBUG=True` will do your static file handling for you since its meant for dev work. `DEBUG=False` is meant for production, but you need to handle your own static assets. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See **[Serve Files During Development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)**

> If you use `django.contrib.staticfiles`, `runserver` will serve staticfiles
> automatically when DEBUG is set to True.

You can inspect `django/staticfile/views.py` to see the `view` that serves the staticfiles. in case of `not settings.DEBUG`, it will `raise Http404`

```
def serve(request, path, insecure=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Serve static files below a given point in the directory structure or
    from locations inferred from the staticfiles finders.
    To use, put a URL pattern such as::
        from django.contrib.staticfiles import views
        path('', views.serve)
    in your URLconf.
    It uses the django.views.static.serve() view to serve the found files.
    """
    if not settings.DEBUG and not insecure:
        raise Http404
    ...
    
    return static.serve(request, path, document_root=document_root, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `python manage.py runserver`. 
Then, check if `DEBUG` is `True` or `False`. Make sure it is `Debug=True`. 
Lastly, see if you accidentally deleted any `static` files.

Comment: DEBUG = TRUE I changed that. But I have question why it worked fine when DEBUG = FALSE... And what is for DEBUG = TRUE important.. I am new to django, sorry.. Thanks.

Comment: So, ```DEBUG=True``` is when you are testing and not in production. If you set ``DEBUG`` to false, you need to add an allowed host in  ``Allowed Hosts``.
I have no clue whatsoever why the static files are disappearing, for that, you should do some research yourself.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676453/what-are-functional-differences-between-debug-true-and-false-in-django#:~:text=Basically%2C%20in%20DEBUG%20mode%2C%20django,ALLOWED_HOSTS%20needs%20to%20be%20set.&text=The%20DEBUG%3DTrue%20%2C%20if%20there,will%20show%20details%20of%20error.).
Anyways, I'm happy I helped!

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand.. What I have to add in allowed host?